# java multithreading , creating object for each thread

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have two class CallISPSubscriberDump (This class reads from Database total no of process id , for each process id it calls ISPSubscriberDump class to create a file) and ISPSubscriberDump (Used to create ISP subscriber dump file which is sent to network for provioning ). 
I am using Executor Service to create multiple threads and passing process id to ISPSubscriberDump in its constructor , But in this approach i have to create as many objects as many threads are running. This process is working fine.
As i have to run a thread for each process Id , is there any other way in which i can create only single object and crate multiple objects?

```
public class CallISPSubscriberDump
{

    public  void createFile()
    {

        List<Integer> totalId = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<String> dataFlag = new ArrayList<String>();


        //Reading process Id and dataFlag from database and populating in list
        try
        {
            if (totalId.size() == 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("No process id found for ISP Dump");
            }
            else
            {
                // MAX_THRAED is max limit of threads
                int maxthred = totalId.size() < Integer.parseInt(logGererator.getProperty("MAX_THRAED")) ? totalId.size() :
                                                Integer.parseInt(logGererator.getProperty("MAX_THRAED"));

                ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(maxthred);

                for (int cnt = 0; cnt < totalId.size(); cnt++)
                {
                    //For a particular thread assigning a particular process I create N object of ISPSubscriberDump for N thread and assign process Id in its constructor
                    executor.execute(new ISPSubscriberDump(totalId.get(cnt),dataFlag.get(cnt)));
                }

                executor.shutdown();

                while (!executor.isTerminated())
                {
                }
                System.out.println("Finished all threads");


            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

```
public class ISPSubscriberDump implements Runnable 
{

    private int processId;
    private String dataFlag;

    public ISPSubscriberDump(int processId,String dataFlag){
        this.processId=processId;
        this.dataFlag=dataFlag;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        // File Creation 
        createFile();
    }

    createFile()
    {
    int currentProcessId=processId;
    String currentDataFlag= dataFlag;
    // File Creation and provising happened here using currentProcessId and currentDataFlag
    }

    }
```

Comment: You could use a queue and have your threads pick object tasks from there.

Comment: Even with Queue i am not able to solve it can you please explain in details

Answer (score -1):

TL;DR

"is there any other way in which i can create only single object and crate multiple objects?"

Maybe you can use a singleton/factory class.